# django - login view in DRF

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have a register view in my django code which works fine:

Working in Django rest framework,

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def register(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now I want to add a login view in order to let users login, I wrote something like this, not sure about this:

```
@list_route(methods=['post'])
    def login(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

couple of questions:

- does it look okay?
- and also, how should I POST to this view? to the register view I POST with json and it works fine. 
  Will json with the username and password work here as well?

Comment: It looks odd. The very idea of REST is for the server to be stateless. The concept of "logging in through REST" sounds wrong. Normally, REST endpoints should be objects, that is, nouns, not verbs. Other than this, there is no reason it would not work. Unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for your answer. thing is, i cant really understand where the actual logging in happening.  in a "classic REST server scenario" (I mean like it should be) ,how does the login happen?? I have the registration working just fine from the android app. now the user wants to login in order to make some requests, where is the actual login?

Comment: You send credentials on every request. The process of logging in usually creates and returns some token that you use on subsequent requests instead of sending user/pass. Django's auth module does that using sessions - the piece of data granting access being the session id, which is  returned to the browser as a cookie. Depending on your setup, you can use that, or you'll need to implement some similar feature (that's what the libs suggested by chandu do).

Comment: @spectras this isnt always the case. Yes a rest api should be stateless but in the context of a Single Page Application, there needs to be some way to create a session for a user to log in to perform restricted actions. I have searched all over the internet to see what is the best login implementation for single page apps and ultimately it lead me right back over to sessions

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant sessions are basically a way to send some form of credentials on every request. That's exactly what I describe in the comment above :)

Answer (score 8):

your *register is listening to post method with @list_route pattern and also you want to bind your *login to post again with @list_route ?!?

it's imposible, if you ask me i prefer to implement my authentication class with APIView type

create your Login(views.APIView)like this:

---

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data

        username = data.get('username', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)

                return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: what is login() ?

Comment: @nassim login is from django.contrib.auth import login

Comment: how can this code return the auth token if you have token authentication setup? so that if you receive the token in the response, then you can authorize all subsequent requests.

Answer (score 6):

You login method is not correct using DRF.
For login you haven’t used the serialzers.
Your can go through these api for login,logout etc for clear understanding

[Djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser)
Djoser library provides a set of views to handle basic actions such as registration, login, logout, password reset and account activation. The package works with a custom user model and it uses token based authentication. This is a ready to use REST implementation of Django authentication system.

[django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py)
Django-rest-auth library provides a set of REST API endpoints for registration, authentication (including social media authentication), password reset, retrieve and update user details, etc. By having these API endpoints, your client apps such as AngularJS, iOS, Android, and others can communicate to your Django backend site independently via REST APIs for user management.

Comment: Please note, that `django-rest-auth` is no longer maintained. But there is it's fork `dj-rest-auth` which is being maintained as of June 2021.